# A finite $\mathbb{Z}$-module whose submodules are totally ordered by inclusion.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

I have the following problem:

> Let $M$ be a finite $\mathbb{Z}$-module such that set of the submodules is totally ordered by inclusion. Prove that there exist a prime $p$ such that $|M|=p^\alpha$ for some $\alpha$.

I'd like some hint to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: In fact, doesn't it have to by cyclic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so a finite $\mathbb{Z}$ module is a finite abelian group ! If its order is divisible by two different primes then there are 2 elements of relatively prime orders, and their subgroups cannot have an  inclusion one in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $L_1$ be the unique minimal submodule; then $L$ must be simple, so…

Let $L_2/L_1$ be the unique minimal submodule of $M/L_1$, so…